# PHP round to precision 2

Tags: php, api, payment, rounding

My payment system takes 0.5% from each transaction.
I have 0.9$ on my account, very small amount.
And when I try to withdraw 0.9$ through API it gives an error, it takes 0.0045$ as fee and rounds to 0.91$.
So I can only withdraw 0.89$ and pay 0.00445$ fee, which is rounded to 1 cent to empty my account;

I can't understand by which formula the additional fee is rounded =(

```
php round(0.9+0.9*0.005,2)
```

returns 0.9$, how to get 0.91$?

Edit: ceil works good for this particular amount, but on practice when I withdraw only 1 cent the comission, which is 0.00005 somehow does not count as 0.01, looks like besides ceil() only first two zeros after point are included. hm..

ceil((0.01*0.005) * 100) / 100; gives 1 cent, but in reality api takes zero.

Comment: Try with round(($value) * 100) / 100

Comment: @IkerVázquez That doesn't work

Comment: `ceil(($value) * 100) / 100` will give 0.91. Not sure if it will give you what you want in every case though

Comment: Sounds like this API has a weird rounding system

Answer (score 6):

How about using [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

```
$number = 0.9*0.005;
$number = ceil(100*$number) / 100; // rounds fee up to nearest cent
$number = $number + 0.9;
echo round($number,2);
```

Comment: I improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do multiplication inside a ceil function! You'll get floating point errors and it can be extremely unpredictable. To avoid this do:

```
function ceiling($value, $precision = 0) {
    $offset = 0.5;
    if ($precision !== 0)
        $offset /= pow(10, $precision);
    return round($value + $offset, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
}
```

For example `ceiling(2.2200001, 2)` will give `2.23`.